# Store mysql data in an array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it somehow possible to store mysql data in an array without having to use a `while` loop in php?
I only have 1 column here.

```
$members = $conn->prepare(Select id from members where state = 'CA');
$members->execute();
//Result ->1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
//$myarray = array of the above results.
$myarray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)//Has to be this kind of array.
```

I'm trying to avoid another while loop here, since this thing goes inside somemore code.

Comment: Even if you find some construct that will not `show` you a loop, it will still have to loop through all the rows to get your data: Hence I think its useless trying to avoid it

Comment: If your output will be in one row only, there is no need of while loop here

Comment: @cartina So, is the answer below the only way to do it? Or you've got a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Look. First of all, you have to understand that it is impossible to put some data into array without a loop. You can sweep a loop under the rug, but you have to understand that it still exists somewhere.

If you are looking for such a syntax sugar, [manual page has an example for you](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try fetch_row function

Comment: That's mysqli, I guess. I'm doing this with php PDO.